# User in student role automatically

Tags: asp.net

In asp.net(C #) I want to automatically add the new users when they sign up in a particular role (student role) i have managed the role but how i can automatically add them or like in more simple words

i want new users to get in Student Role by default

what are the codes and processure please help !!

Comment: What kind of authorization mechanism are you using?

Comment: i am using visual studio 2010

Answer (score 1):

In the CreatedUser event of the create user wizard simply add the line

```
Roles.AddUserToRole(CreateUserWizard1.UserName, "Student");
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, it is difficult to tell how best to achieve this.

I would simply set the role to `Student` in the user class constructor.

Comment: there are no codes as i am testing it .. look wat i want is as new user sign up it directly gets added to Student role so i could deny the Students to access Teachers page ..

Comment: look i am making raw there is nothing real stuff which i can show u but heres something: i managed roles from asp.net configuration and deny access to role(Student) to access teachers page and now i want the new users to directly get added to students role so they can not access Teachers page

Comment: @mAs - But how are you _assigning_ users to a role in the first place?

Comment: this what i want !! to how to add users directly to a particular role